# How to find the maximum of lookup values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have an excel table that looks like this

```
Row    Column1    Column2    Column3
R1     A          B          C 
R2     C          D          X
```

I have a table that holds the values corresponding to the entries in Columns 1 to 3 which looks like this -

```
Key    Value
A      1
B      7
C      2
D      4
X      9
```

I want to create a `Column4` that has the maximum looked-up value of columns 1 to 3, i.e. the result would look like this -

```
Row    Column1    Column2    Column3    Looked_Up_Max
R1     A          B          C          7
R2     C          D          X          9
```

I tried writing an array formula like this - 
`={max(if(B1:D1,vlookup(B1:D1,lookup_table!$A$1:$B$5,2,0)))}`

But it does not work. Any way to do this is one step instead of say creating three additional columns with the looked up values and then taking a max of the additional columns?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data on the lookup table is sorted then you can use this array formula:

```
=MAX(LOOKUP(B2:D2,$H$2:$H$5,$I$2:$I$5))
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

Another that does not care about sort order that uses SUMIFS()

```
=MAX(SUMIFS(I:I,H:H,B2:D2))
```

Still an array formula, but this assumes that the Key in the lookup is unique.

[image]

---

If not in order and not unique and the user wants the first then we need this convoluted array formula:

```
=MAX(IFERROR(INDEX(I:I,N(IF({1},MATCH(B2:D2,H:H,0)))),-1E+99))
```

Still and Array formula.

[image]